# RAM underperforming - Shows 333 MHz instead of 667 MHz

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-10, memory

I have an old laptop Acer 6930. There are 2 RAMs in it and both of them are 667 MHz:

[image]

---

When I checked in CPUZ , it shows like this:

[image]

Is there anything wrong with it?

Besides it shows as 333 MHz in CPUZ instead of 667 MHz. Laptop became very slow after having these 2 RAMs.

Answer (score 2):

As always, it’s [DDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR_SDRAM) – Double Data Rate. What’s advertised is the “effective frequency”, which is double the real frequency because it can transfer data two times per cycle (both rising and falling edge).

333.33 MHz * 2 = 666.67 MHz.

As you can see on your RAM module and in CPU-Z, it’s PC5300, which means 333.33 MHz.

If it’s really running at 333.33 MHz (you only show screenshots of what the modules are capable of), everything is running as it should.

Comment: ok i understood something now...do you want to see any other screenshots? I just want to know if it's running as usual with full potential.

Comment: @Karthik IIRC the “Memory” tab shows the actual frequency currently in use. That being said, slow memory is not very likely to cause serious slowdowns. So those are probably the result of something else.

Answer (score 1):

The 333Mhz is pretty accurate, since that's the Jedec specification for a 667Mhz module.

Keep in mind that DDRx (where x in 1,2,3 etc) stands for double data rate, which means that the 333 value you see translates to ~667.

I also dont think that the performance slowdown is related to the above